# How to navigate to a new page using WinUI3 with C++ desktop app?

Tags: c++-winrt, winui-3

Firstly I create a project using template "Blank App, Packaged(WinUI in Desktop)" in Visual Studio.

Then I changed code in MainWindow.xaml to a simple Frame:

```
<Frame x:Name="rootFrame"></Frame>
```

And then I add a BlankPage and try to navigate to the BlankPage like this:

```
rootFrame().Navigate(xaml_typename<BlankPage>());
```

And then visual studio give me error:

```
winrt\Windows.UI.Xaml.Interop.h(643,29): error C2338: T must be WinRT type.
```

I don't know how to do...

Comment: The WinUI team is actively answering questions in [Github issues](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues).

Comment: What's the definition of `BlankPage`?

Comment: @IInspectable BlankPage is a page template provide by visual studio: Right click project-Add new item-Blank Page(WinUI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found what's wrong. It's relate to namespace, when I create a new Page, there are three namespace:

```
winrt::PROJECTNAME::implementation::BlankPage
winrt::PROJECTNAME::factory_implementation::BlankPage
PROJECTNAME::BlankPage
```

I should use PROJECTNAME::BlankPage defined in BlankPage.idl

Comment: [What do the *projected type* and the *implementation type* mean?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/faq#what-do-the-projected-type-and-the-implementation-type-mean)